# systemd-ask-password-console and systemd-cryptsetup after ssh.target with attached password prompt with no timeout

Tags: systemd

My goal is to delay the unlocking of this USB to after the system has booted with the `ssh.service` active and don't ever timeout until it is typed. The timeout still happens however and proceeds to `getty`. You can't type your password once the password prompt comes up (the TTY isn't attached)

I've been copying what `auto` in `/etc/crypttab` results in via `systemd-cryptsetup-generator`. I've also been looking at `systemctl list-dependencies` to see that `sysinit.target` does `systemd-ask-password-console.path` to attach to the console TTY.

*/etc/crypttab*

```
crypt   /dev/disk/by-label/crypt        none    nofail,noauto,timeout=0,x-systemd.device-timeout=0
```

*/etc/systemd/system/finish.target*

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount crypt USB
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=systemd-cryptsetup@crypt.service systemd-ask-password-console.path
After=ssh.target
Before=getty@tty1.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I do `Wants=mnt-crypt.mount` or `Wants=dev-mapper-crypt.device` it actually respects the timeouts, but does still not accept password input.

`ls -la /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/finish.target`

```sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 33 Jun  6 00:04 /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/finish.target -> /etc/systemd/system/finish.target
```

`systemctl list-dependencies`

```
●   ├─finish.target
●   │ ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
●   │ ├─systemd-cryptsetup@crypt.service
    │   └─...
```

If I do `systemctl restart systemd-ask-password-console.service` I can actually start typing the password and it works as expected both on the executing terminal and the console on the screen (`/dev/tty1`).

Its seems like there is a relationship somewhere which prevents `systemd-ask-password-console` start after initial boot, because it will gladly start later along-side `systemd-ask-password-wall`.

Same if I copy it and edit it as a new service, it will also start the `systemd-ask password --watch --console` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I figured you could not reuse any of the builtin units because they are depending heavily on units early in the boot process. We have to create our own units and use pretty much plain commands.

These comes with a default timeout of 300s with unlock (Remove if you desire), then it will as normal notify via wall with other password requests after the timeout.

We disable the ask-password-wall services and then query a single password at console. Why not use `systemd-ask-password-console.path|systemd-ask-password-console.service` ?

- Because it also is deeply tied to the early boot process and is launched with `--watch` for multiple queries as we only need 1 in this case.

As you can see `attach-crypt-usb.service` has `BindsTo=systemd-cryptsetup@crypt.device`, this is first of all because of integration and secondly because otherwise the mount unit `mnt-crypt.mount` would trigger systemd-cryptsetup trying to attach the dm-disk simultaneously once requested.

If you have any inputs or feedback, feel free to leave it - I will come back and update as it is battle-tested.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/crypt-usb.target
[Unit]
Description= Mount crypt USB late at boot

Before= getty@tty1.service

After= sysinit.target

Conflicts= systemd-ask-password-wall.service systemd-ask-password-wall.path systemd-ask-password-console.service systemd-ask-password-console.path
Wants= attach-crypt-usb.service unlock-crypt-usb.service mount-crypt-usb.service

[Install]
WantedBy= multi-user.target
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/attach-crypt-usb.service
[Unit]
Description= Attach Crypt USB

After= dm-event.service

# requires After=dm-event.service
ConditionPathExists= !/dev/mapper/crypt

ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink= /dev/disk/by-label/crypt

# To avoid mnt-crypt.mount attempting systemd-cryptsetup@crypt.device
Conflicts= umount.target systemd-cryptsetup@crypt.service
BindsTo= dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-crypt.device
After= dev-disk-by\x2dlabel-crypt.device

[Service]
ExecStart= /lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach 'crypt' '/dev/disk/by-label/crypt' 'none' 'nofail,noauto'
ExecStop= /usr/bin/umount /mnt/crypt
ExecStopPost= /usr/sbin/cryptsetup close crypt
Type= exec
RemainAfterExit= true
Restart= on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy= crypt-usb.target
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/unlock-crypt-usb.service
[Unit]
Description= Unlock Crypt USB on console

Before= mount-crypt-usb.service
After= attach-crypt-usb.service dm-event.service

# requires After=dm-event.service
ConditionPathExists= !/dev/mapper/crypt

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec= 300
ExecStart= /usr/bin/systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --query --console=/dev/tty1
Type= oneshot
RemainAfterExit= yes

[Install]
WantedBy= crypt-usb.target
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/mount-crypt-usb.service
[Unit]
Description= Mount crypt USB and reactivate ask-password-wall

After= unlock-crypt-usb.service dev-mapper-crypt.device

Wants= mnt-crypt.mount

[Service]
ExecStart= /usr/bin/systemctl start systemd-ask-password-wall.service systemd-ask-password-wall.path
Type= oneshot
RemainAfterExit= yes

[Install]
WantedBy= crypt-usb.target
```